# How to get data as a list in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

In SQL-Server I have a table which contains data like:

```
----------
ID value
----------
1     p-10
----------
2     p-16
----------
1     p-11
----------
2     p-21
----------
3     p-30
----------
```

I want to select the data to get output as:

```
----------
ID    value
----------
1     p-10,p-11
----------
2     p-16,p-21
----------
3     p-30
----------
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Try this   select  distinct
  Country,
  STUFF((SELECT  ',' + (p.City) 
            FROM bdo.TableName AS a where a.Country=b.Country
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') AS Cities 
  from bdo.TableName AS b